# How to do automatic icon slideshow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I would like to do an automatic icon slideshow. See example on the webpage below. You have to scroll down to the footer section.
Any suggestions how this could be implemented?
Using nextjs and tailwind in my project.

https://spoton.ch/

Comment: It's CSS animation. Possibly set inline through JavaScript: https://nimb.ws/qNm3SI

Answer (score 0):

making a slider container with `width:100vw` & `height:300px`which is the height of the pictures I have planned to use you can choose yours. and overflow hidden to hide the pictures that are overflowing outside the screen.

putting pictures inside the `logoSlider` with `display:flex;` to make the pictures set in one line. the `logoSlider` is also inside the the main parent `sliderContainer`.
this is just an example & animation might not be accurate as i am here to just you an idea & you can tweak the animation to your liking..

creating an animation of infinite to move the pictures across the screen.

```css
.sliderContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
}

.logoSlider>img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.logoSlider {
  display: flex;
  animation: slideshow 6s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  from {
    transform: translate(800px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-1800px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="logoSlider">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/apple-logo.png">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/google-logo.png">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/microsoft-logo.png">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/samsung-logo.png">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/walt-disney-logo.png">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.designcrowd.com/blog/100-Famous-Brand%20Logos-From-The-Most-Valuable-Companies-of-2020/intel-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```